# How to run a golang restful api as service in ubuntu server

Tags: server, scripts, services, webserver, golang

I need to run golang restful server that build using gin framework and mongodb as service in my ubuntu server.how can do this?
(every time i run the go script i need to this also gvm use go1.4)

Answer (score 1):

You can build the go binary and create a systemd service to run it as a service.

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/go_app.service`

Use the following example for the .service config.

```
[Unit]
Description=My example go application
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/opt/go_app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Source: https://www.atpeaz.com/running-go-app-as-a-service-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

- You can create a binary for the application by running `go build` (or similar command for your application). The build should be for Linux (`export GOOS=Linux`).
- You then copy the build to the server (the binary) to an appropriate location (say, `/var/www/webapp` or `/opt/webapp`) and make sure you have `root` as the owner of the binary (or you can setup a dedicated `webappuser` user for your application) as well as provide executable permission to the binary (`chmod +x /var/www/webapp`)
- You then have 2 options - Either use a process manager (such as `supervisor`) or use Ubuntu's native `systemd` for basically writing a *service* file for your application

1. Supervisor can be simply installed for ubuntu as `apt-get install supervisor`. Once it's installed you can write a manager script for your app, like so:

```
[program:webapp]
command=/var/www/webapp
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/webapp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/webapp.out.log
```

You need to write this file as `webapp.conf` in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/webapp.conf`. Once this file's written, you need to reload the supervisor by running `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update`. Then your application will start running as a service through Supervisor.

2. The other option is to use `systemd`'s native capabilities. You can simply write a file in the location `/lib/systemd/system/webapp.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Golang Web application
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/var/www/webapp
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once this is written, you run `systemctl daemon-reload`; `systemctl start webapp.service` and `systemctl enable webapp.service`. Then your application will start running as a service through Systemd.

I generally go with the preference of writing service files through supervisor as it allows you to control only the applications deployed by you. Also, you might have observed that I've written something about the log files in my sample config. This basically allows me to control the log location and how my application's logs are written (i.e where are the errors and where are the application's logs). This also helps to stream that particular files to an external log management service (say AWS Cloudwatch)